# In My Case I got: app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, require, tron, tronweb

I can't found for exactly my example any solution.

app.js:

```
 const TronWeb = require("tronweb");


const tronWeb = new TronWeb({
    fullHost: "https://api.shasta.trongrid.io"
});


const publicAddress = tronWeb.defaultAddress.base58

console.log(publicAddress);
```

index.html:

```
    <script src="tronweb.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

**localhost/index.html I got error.**
With using in terminal node app.js works" I want to display in page index.html and is the same way.
Maybe missing library? I have tried to transfer from github but I got always the same error.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/require,  do you have it in your package.json file?

Comment: require() is node-specific server side method.